# Could not load hostfxr.dll - Windows Server 12

Tags: iis, .net-core

I deployed my app on IIS and I get this error: Could not load hostfxr.dll.
When I try to load the app through console I am able to load it and navigate to localhost:5001.

The patch that keeps coming up on google won't work for my machine.

I've added `UseIISIntegration();` and I've tried `UseISS()`. Neither fixed the issue.

Could this be an IIS issue? I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Run a report to rule out the common causes, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: This might be caused by a bitness mismatch between IIS application pool and published application. You can try to set "Enable 32 bits applications" to true in the settings of the application pool.